# white space generates error in vagrant ssh command

Tags: ssh, vagrant, yaml, virtualbox, homestead

I tried to boot the virtual machine up using the homestead box. In order to check if things have gone correctly, I run the following command

```
  vagrant ssh
```

However, the white space in the user's path is not recognized and I get the following error:

```
   $ vagrant ssh 
   Warning: Identitiy file C:/Users/John not accessible: No such file
   or directory
   bash: Doe/Homestead/.vagrant/machines/homestead-7/virtualbox/private_key:
   No such file or directory
```

My Homestead.yaml originally looked like this:

```
   ---
   ip: "(NOT DISCLOSED)"
   memory: 2048
   cpus: 1
   provider: virtualbox

  authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

  keys:
  - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

  folders:
  - map: ~/code
  to: /home/vagrant/code

  sites:
 - map: test.app
   to: /home/vagrant/code/fresh/public

  databases:
 - homestead
 - fresh
```

WHAT I'VE TRIED:

1)Adding full paths to the Homestead.yaml file like so:

```
   C:/Users/John Doe/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Outcome: same error message as above.

2)Adding full paths AND quotation marks to the Homestead.yaml file:

```
  "C:/Users/John Doe/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

Outcome: same error message as above.

and like that...

```
  C:/Users/"John Doe"/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Outcome: same error message as above

Also, tried escaping the white space with a backslash and writing a `%` instead of the space. Outcome: virtual machine didn't boot up at all.

How can I make sure the white space does not get in the way when I run the `vagrant ssh` command? I am using Windows 10.

Comment: You YAML is not syntactically correct, it will not load.